# MUI icon shows up on dev tools but doesn't render

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on MUI icons in React, and realized my icons were not rendering even after npm installing @mui/icons-material and importing:

```
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";
```

Dev tool tells me that the svg is there, but it's not rendered no matter what color I change it to. Is there a step I missed by any chance? I've double checked the installation instructions but haven't found anything.

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe no extra step is needed if you've installed material ui icons using `npm` or any other package manager by using [this link](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation)

```bash
npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled @mui/icons-material
```

you can test if the icon is there but not with the right `width` or `height` by trying to create a new `div` outside of the other elements. First, try with some text, if they were visible then try putting the icon inside, like the code below:

```
<div>
  <HomeIcon/>
</div>
```

It should show the HomeIcon.

Otherwise, I'd recommend using this style for the element that you're using to make sure as a parent element it doesn't prevent showing the icon, like:

```css
[parent_element_selector] { 
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: red;
}
```

I hope it helps fixing the problem.

Comment: Changing the size helped - It seems like the default padding was taking over the icon space. Thanks for the help!